# Чтобы в языке C++ функция-нечлен была статической, достаточно ли написать static только в объявлении, а в определении не писать?

Tags: c++

Вопрос, собственно, в заголовке.

Comment: Никогда не понимал какой смысл имеет заголовки статической функции если она объявляется только для текущего файла?

Comment: @igumnov: Например, если вы хотите задекларировать функцию в начале файла, а использовать в конце? Такое пригодится для взаимно-рекурсивных функций.

Comment: Меня интересует сокрытие локальных функций в файле реализации.

Comment: Это сокрытие на деле только условность. В реальности ничто не мешает вам взять со static фукнкции указатель и передать его в любое место программы.

Comment: `static` скрывает на самом деле лишь _имя_, не саму _функцию_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да. Как сказано в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15670259/276994), главное, чтобы *первая* видимая декларация была статической.

Comment: PS: подправил ответ, убрал лишний текст насчёт заголовочных файлов. Выносить статические функции в заголовочный файл не имеет смысла.